# Get variables inside {{ }} using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jinja2

Let's say we have a data on a webpage (for example: "Name: Bill Gates"). When we inspect the data on the browser we find:

```
<b> Name </b>: Bill Gates
```

but when we scrape it using BeautifulSoup, the name is actually a variable (like in jinja template) and we end up with

```
<b> Name </b>: {{ name }}
```

Is there a way to extract the {{ name }} value (i.e. "Bill Gates") using BeautifulSoup ?

I didn't find an answer to that on internet (maybe didn't use the right keywords? any suggestions ?)

(Example: extracting names from  https://orcid.org/orcid-search/quick-search/?searchQuery=mario%20franca)

Comment: This will not be Jinja, but some kind of front-end templating system, possibly Angular.

Comment: As stated above, probably the html template for angular. If you provide the url I can look to see if it's within the script tags, or if there's a separate request made to get that data.

Comment: I just edited the post with the example website. It's within a script tags. I got to the script data but I can't extract the variables values.

Comment: So… you want "Bill Gates" as result, or "{{ name }}"…?

Comment: I want "Bill Gates"

Comment: @Yassine , the question was closed before I could post my solution. I don't think it's as straight forward as posted in duplicate question link. Shoot me an email and I give you my solution jason.schvach@gmail.com